# Getting error while implement facebook ads in android application

Tags: android, facebook

Failed to find provider info for `com.facebook.katana.provider.PlatformProvider`

When I install Facebook app then this error is not occur, but another error occur:

```
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5ced1368 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x5e928a18 arg=0x0
E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x5ced1368 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_ECDSA
```

and my ads is not shown..

Comment: do you want to advertise in your android application along with facebook login ?If so please refer to Admob tutorial.

Comment: Admob is google ads. but i want facebook ads

Answer (score 0):

In the Gradle File(Module:app):

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
```

In Your Activity:

```
 com.facebook.ads.AdView adView;
adView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this,"PLACEMENTID",com.facebook.ads.AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
((LinearLayout) adContainer).addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();
```